# How do you compare timestamps?

Tags: timestamp, hsqldb

Seems a bit trivial question but the behavior I get using hsqldb is counter intuitive.
The following select returns no rows (given the fact the I previously inserted 2 rows with the timestamp value equal to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`):

```
SELECT * FROM webshop.transactions t WHERE (t.expiration_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I expect this might happen due to the fact that before comparison the timestamp is converted into a number, which might be negative. This would explain the results but still raises the question how in general to compare timestamps?

Comment: This one worked for me:  `SELECT * FROM webshop.Transactions t WHERE CAST(t.expiration_time AS DATE) <= NOW()`

Answer (score 2):

If the WEBSHOP.TRANSACTIONS.EXPIRATION_TIME column is defined as TIMESTAMP, then your comparison is correct. HSQLDB supports TIMESTAMP natively as a data type that can be compared.

Comment: It is defined as TIMESTAMP but comparison works wrong. If I convert it to DATE then it works as expected.

Comment: I have checked this and it works with the latest 1.8.3 and 2.2.5 versions. May be some problem with the version you are using.

Comment: Which time-zone are you in? I can test with your time-zone. Also try with LOCALTIMESTAMP instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two strings, which is definitely not what you want. See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) for examples on how to do this correctly. Basically, instead of `t.expiration_time`, use `t.expiration_time+0` to force a conversion to a number. Ditto for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

(I couldn't find a link specific to hsqldb, but the principle is the same.)

Comment: Unlike MySQL, HSQLDB supports SQL types natively according to the SQL Standard. See the Guide here: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html